# Portfolio gallery with filtering categories

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried edit **Portfolio gallery with filtering categories** from

> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_portfolio_filter.asp

I wanted to add animation by choosing category but I failed.

Here is my code:

```
/*Portfolio-gallery*/
/* Add padding BETWEEN each column (if you want) */
.row,
.row > .column {
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 398px;
    display: none; /* Hide columns by default */
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    transition:         all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1); 
}

/* Clear floats after rows */ 
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    transition:         all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1); 
}

/* Content */
.content {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    transition:         all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1); 
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    transition:         all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1); 
}
```

Comment: would you create a full example (HTML, JS, CSS), it's difficult to understand what's does not work.

Comment: lol column width animation ? maybe ?

Comment: maybe you can check this [css3 transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transition` attribute will not work on `display` attribute.
But you can add the transition by setting below CSS using `height` and `visibility`

```
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    transition:         all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1); 
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 325px;
}
```

But here you must define the height of the card that being shown here.

Comment: I don't know but after edit by your codes categories is not working :/

Comment: actually it is working thank you very much man appreciate it rep+

Answer (score 0):

i can't comment so i had to do it this way.

i used this code for my portfolio and worked great!

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="portfolioFilter clearfix">
      <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">All Categories</a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".webTemplates">Web Templates</a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".logos">Logos</a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".drawings">Drawings</a>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".ui">UI Elements</a>
    </div>
      </div>
    <div class="portfolioContainer">

      <div class="webTemplates objects">
        <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/cc99b535336825.Y3JvcCwxMzk1LDEwOTEsMCw3ODA.png" alt="image">
      </div>

      <div class="drawings places">
        <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/d4cfa934191261.Y3JvcCw2MTMsNDc5LDQsMjA0.jpg" alt="image">
      </div>

      <div class="webTemplates food">
        <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/11893193.5482088f6f391.png" alt="image">
      </div>

      <div class="logos drawings">
        <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/be4b9728308865.55b92edb950fc.jpg" alt="image">
      </div>

      <div class="webTemplates">
        <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/12963199.548365055868a.png" alt="image">
      </div>

      <div class="ui">
        <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/20342607.5434c04b49254.png" alt="image">
      </div>

      <div class="drawings">
        <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/b11bbb26474383.555f91fd42584.jpg" alt="image">
      </div>

      <div class="webTemplates">
        <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/14385875.548573dae7a09.jpg" alt="image">
      </div>

      <div class="drawings">
        <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/14569777.5485b3876a1b9.png" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="logos">
        <img src=" https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/1d854a24500155.5505cccd057a4.jpg" alt="image">
      </div>
      <div class="ui">
        <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/f9b95b26406487.555cc1fded76f.jpg" alt="image">
      </div>

      <div class="logos">
        <img src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/projects/202/181a7b35469661.Y3JvcCw3NjUsNTk5LDY3LDA.png" alt="image">
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.portfolioFilter {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.portfolioFilter a {
  margin-right: 6px;
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 4px 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.portfolioFilter a.current {
  background: #1e1e1e;
  border: 1px solid #1e1e1e;
  color: #f9f9f9;
}
.portfolioContainer{
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
img {
  margin: 5px;
  max-width:100%;
}

.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}

.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
  /* change duration value to whatever you like */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope {
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
  -moz-transition-property: height, width;
  transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $container = $('.portfolioContainer');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
    });

    $('.portfolioFilter a').click(function(){
        $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
         });
         return false;
    }); 
});
```

hope it will help you, good luck!